# Regex to change last 2 numbers in set of 6 on condition

Tags: regex

This number is in a filename string eg. `abcdefg-sdasdfg-123410.txt`
I am using an application which is changing the filename and can use regex.
If there is a number at the end of the filename, such as `123410`, I need to change the last 2 digits so it will be `123411`.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: What language is this for? A possible regex to capture the last 6 digits in a group is '-(\d+)\.' assuming that the strings are always formatted like that.

Comment: It isn't a language, the application allows use for regex and string replace in an input box, but only the Regex takes into consideration the '.' extension. Therefore making it hard to replace 10 with 11 at the end of the filename. The Regex gives me a 'Match' and 'Replace' option, the condition is always 10 to 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which regex variant you're using, try something like this:

```
Search for: (.*)10(\..*)
Replace with: ${1}11${2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++:

```
Find what: ([0-9]+)[0-9][0-9].
Replace with: \111.
```